# how to extract specific keys from json

Tags: jq

I have following json input file. I need to get the 2 and 3rd keys like below.

Need out put as:

```
test, 2021.1.2
dev, 2021.2.2
test, 2021.1.2
dev, 2021.2.1
test, 2021.3.1
```

Input json:

```
[
  {
    "builds": {
      "test": {
        "2021.1.2": {
          "stages": [
            "functional",
            "integration"
          ]
        }
      },
      "dev": {
        "2021.2.2": {
          "stages": [
            "junit",
            "nls"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "dockertag": "0.1.1"
  },
  {
    "builds": {
      "test": {
        "2021.1.2": {
          "stages": [
            "functional"
          ]
        }
      },
      "dev": {
        "2021.2.1": {
          "stages": [
            "junit",
            "nls"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "dockertag": "0.1.2"
  },
  {
    "builds": {
      "test": {
        "2021.3.1": {
          "stages": [
            "functional",
            "integration"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "dockertag": "0.1.3"
  }
]
```

I tried following code but it is incomplete. I can get the 2nd key but not sure how to further extract 3rd key:

```
jq -r '.[].builds | keys[] as $k | "\($k), \(.[$k] | .)"' test.json
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.[].builds | to_entries[] | "\(.key), \(.value | keys[])"
```

Will generate

```
"test, 2021.1.2"
"dev, 2021.2.2"
"test, 2021.1.2"
"dev, 2021.2.1"
"test, 2021.3.1"
```

---

Use `jq --raw-output` to remove the `"`'s around each line

---

[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/8MChru9MRB)

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches using the path:

---

```sh
jq -r '.[].builds | paths | select(length == 2) | join(", ")'
```

```
test, 2021.1.2
dev, 2021.2.2
test, 2021.1.2
dev, 2021.2.1
test, 2021.3.1
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/KuIhFCYpNE)

---

```sh
jq -r 'path(.[].builds[][])[2:] | join(", ")'
```

```
test, 2021.1.2
dev, 2021.2.2
test, 2021.1.2
dev, 2021.2.1
test, 2021.3.1
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/fdplQcKV6i)

Comment: This worked too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ruby if your `jq` is broken that day:

```
ruby -r json -e 'JSON.parse($<.read).
                 each{|h| h.select{|k,v| k=="builds"}.
                 each{|k,v| ["test","dev"].
                 each{|t| puts "#{t}, #{v[t].keys[0]}" if v.key?(t)}}} ' file    

test, 2021.1.2
dev, 2021.2.2
test, 2021.1.2
dev, 2021.2.1
test, 2021.3.1
```